# Adobe Flex : Popup dialog not sizing correctly

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a popup dialog that is an mx:TitleWindow.  The rendered height of the dialog is too large however, see the whitespace at the bottom.  Decreasing the height by x pixels seems to have no effect.  How do I get it to size correctly?

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="356" height="322"
     layout="vertical" showCloseButton="true" close="cancel(event)"
     title="Add User" creationComplete="usernameTF.setFocus();"
     hasFocusableChildren="true">

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.adobe.crypto.SHA1;
        import com.hurlant.crypto.hash.SHA1;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        [Bindable]
        public var mainApp:Object = null; 

        protected function apply_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (usernameTF.text == null || usernameTF.text.length < 1) {
                usernameTF.errorString = "The username is mandatory";
                width = 520;
                return;
            }
            else if (mainApp.userExists(usernameTF.text)) {
                usernameTF.errorString = "Username already exists";
                width = 520;
                return;
            }
            else {
                usernameTF.errorString = "";
            }

            if (passwordTF.text == null || passwordTF.text.length < 1) {
                passwordTF.errorString = "The password is mandatory";
                width = 520;
                return;
            }
            else {
                passwordTF.errorString = "";
            }

            if (confirmTF.text == null || confirmTF.text.length < 1) {
                confirmTF.errorString = "The confirmation password is mandatory";
                width = 520;
                return;
            }
            else {
                confirmTF.errorString = "";
            }               

            if (passwordTF.text != confirmTF.text) {
                passwordTF.errorString = "The passwords must match";
                width = 520;
                return;
            }
            else {
                passwordTF.errorString = "";
            }

            var u:Object = new Object();
            u.username = usernameTF.text;
            u.password =  com.adobe.crypto.SHA1.hash(passwordTF.text);
            u.accesslevel = accessLevelCB.selectedItem;

            mainApp.addUserToModel(u);
            mainApp.applyHandler(null);
        }

        protected function cancel(event:Event):void {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Form height="280" defaultButton="{apply}">
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout gap="{Globals.FORM_GAP}"/>
    </s:layout>                 
    <s:FormHeading label="Add User"/>
    <s:FormItem label="Username:">
        <s:TextInput id="usernameTF" restrict="0-9A-Za-z_." maxChars="127"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Password:">
        <s:TextInput maxChars="127" id="passwordTF" displayAsPassword="true"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Confirm Password:">
        <s:TextInput maxChars="127" id="confirmTF" displayAsPassword="true"/>
    </s:FormItem>       
    <s:FormItem label="Access Level:">
        <s:ComboBox id="accessLevelCB" selectedIndex="0">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <mx:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>user</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>admin</fx:String>
                </mx:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>               
        </s:ComboBox>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button id="apply" label="Apply" click="apply_clickHandler(event)" />
            <s:Spacer width="3"/>
            <s:Button label="Cancel" click="cancel(event)"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

[image: Popup Dialog Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Decreasing the height by x pixels

Which height are you decreasing?

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="356" height="322"
     layout="vertical" showCloseButton="true" close="cancel(event)"
     title="Add User" creationComplete="usernameTF.setFocus();"
     hasFocusableChildren="true">


<s:Form height="280" defaultButton="{apply}">
```

In the code you show I would expect the height of the box to be 322.  The form would be 280; which leaves ~42 pixels of whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, made height of title window and form both 100% and it's working nicely now.